# How to share an android application with facebook and twitter button which is in this application

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-sharing

I developed an android application. I want to put this application buttons of facebook and twitter, and I want to share my android application when the buttons are clicked. How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to need : Facebook SDK, OpenSSL to get HashedKey.

More about with Step by Step guide you can visit here:

[Android Facebook Post Integration with Sharing Button on your APP](http://www.androidgiveaway.com/facebook-sharing-sample-example-in-android-facebook-integration-with-android-app-tutorial/)